# Set key explicitly for a Kafka KTable

Tags: java

I have a Json message which I want to process via Kafka KTable.
The message is :
`{
  "table": "TEST.S_ORDER_ITEM",
  "op_type": "I",
  "op_ts": "test1",
  "current_ts": "2017-07-28T09:09:45.022000",
  "pos": "00000000010000006413",
  "after": {
    "ROW_ID": "2-21DSRY",
    "LAST_UPD": "2014-05-24:00:00:00",
    "ORDER_ID": "2-21DSRY",
    "LAST_UPD_BY": "0-1",
    "ACTIVE_FLG": "WCW==",
    "BU_ID": "1-ENQCIQ",
    "ORDER_NUM": "2-96612816484",
    "REV_NUM": "1",
    "ORDER_DT": "2014-05-24:00:00:00",
    "REQ_SHIP_DT": "2014-06-10:00:00:00",
    "ACCNT_ID": "1-1G9MA10",
    "CONTACT_ID": "1-1GGZ1LF",
    "INTEGRATION_ID": null,
    "QUOTE_ID": null,
    "SHIP_CON_ID": "1-1GGZ1LF",
    "STATUS_CD": "Pending",
    "X_CLOSE_DT": null,
    "X_CUST_REF": "548304383-761",
    "X_SUB_STAT": "COMPLETE",
    "PROCESS_TIMESTAMP": "2017-04-19:15:27:34.786214000",
    "SOFT_DELETE": "N"
  }
}`

Is it possible to have a KTable storing the data in KTable format , where the key will be the ROW_ID from the above message.

I can do the same using KStream, but the problem  is every time I want updated data .
I did the same in KStream using :

```
 KStream<String, JsonNode> orderstre = streams.filter((k, v) -> v.path("table").asText      ().equals("TEST.S_ORDER"))
             .map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.path("after").path("ROW_ID").asText(), v));
```